# Cannot load log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to load specific settings for a Log4j logger. Code was working with version 1.2.17. Now with version 2.21.1 it is not loading the file and it is loading "default" settings.

I'm working with JavaSE-17 (jdk-17.0.1)

I had this code in 1.2.17 to load properties file:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
....
String fileRoute = "D:/code/price-3/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(propPath);

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

But version 2.21.1 does not have "PropertyConfigurator".

I tryed, unsuccessfully, these options (individually):

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

String fileRoute = "D:/code/price-3/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/log4j.properties";

//Test 1
Configurator.initialize(null, fileRoute);

//Test 2
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(URI.create("file:" + fileRoute));

//Test 3
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File f = new File(fileRoute);
context.setConfigLocation(f.toURI());

//test logger
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);

if (logger.isTraceEnabled())
    System.out.println("Trace level");

if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
    System.out.println("Debug level");

if (logger.isInfoEnabled())
    System.out.println("Info level");

if (logger.isWarnEnabled())
    System.out.println("Warn level");

if (logger.isErrorEnabled())
    System.out.println("Error level");

if (logger.isFatalEnabled())
    System.out.println("Fatal level");

logger.trace("Log write");
logger.debug("Log write");
logger.info("Log write");
logger.warn("Log write");
logger.error("Log write");
logger.fatal("Log write");

System.out.println("Name: " + logger.getName());
System.out.println("Level: " + logger.getLevel());
System.out.println("Class: " + logger.getClass());
```

After execution I got this in console:

```
Error level
Fatal level
10:09:55.113 [main] ERROR tu.MyClass- Log write
10:09:55.118 [main] FATAL tu.MyClass- Log write
Name: tu.MyClass
Level: ERROR
Class: class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
```

Console log output is the "default setting".

This is the log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, A0

#appender
log4j.appender.A0=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A0.append=true

#log
log4j.appender.A0.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.A0.MaxBackupIndex=5

#log path and name
log4j.appender.A0.File=logs/price.log

#type and pattern
log4j.appender.A0.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A0.Append=true
log4j.appender.A0.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.A0.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

How can I load it and how can I check it it was successfully loaded?

Comment: Why are you performing explicit loading and not allowing the config to be loaded in the normal way?

Comment: Can you give me an example of "loaded in normal way"? properties files are in a specific directory.

Comment: I mean if you put your config file in your source root, it will end up in `WEB-INF/classes` and be loaded automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Major versions bumps allow for breaking changes. In the case of Log4j, the **configuration format** and default configuration file name changed between 1.x and 2.x.

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146138/11748454) to convert from `log4j.properties` to `log4j2.xml` by:

- Downloading the [binary distribution](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) from Log4j's site and unzipping it in a `bin` folder,
- Running:

  ```sh
  java -cp "bin/*" org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationConverter \
    --in log4j.properties \
    --out log4j2.xml \
    --verbose
  ```

I agree with [G00se's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77963222/cannot-load-log4j-properties-file#comment137445127_77963222): don't use programmatic configuration. It is not required since Log4j 1.0.

The standard locations are:

- `WEB-INF/log4j2.xml` in your WAR file if you [use `log4j-web` or `log4j-jakarta-web`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html#configuration) (highly recommended). This probably corresponds to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml` in your project's folder.
- `log4j2.xml` in your application classpath. Thir probably corresponds to `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` in your project's folder.

**Remark:** The converter will replace your `%-5p` pattern with `%-5v1Level`. While the latter pattern assures 100% compatibility with Log4j 1.x custom levels (cf. [LOG4J2-3419](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3419)), it requires the `log4j-1.2-api` artifact. You should probably change it back to `%-5p`.

Comment: By design, al properties files are in a specific directory inside WEB-INF, like WEB-INF/properties. That is the reasin that I tryed to load it manually

Comment: You can override the default `WEB-INF/log4j2.xml` location with the servlet context parameter `log4jConfiguration` (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)). I would only advise you not to use the Log4j 2.x properties format: it is a pain to write and debug.