# Log4j is not writing logs into file

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2

Thanks in Advance, I am trying to write logs into a file using log4j, I have tried all log4j.properties but nothing worked. Below is the code.

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class Main {
        final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            logger.info("Hello and welcome!");
    
            // Press Shift+F10 or click the green arrow button in the gutter to run the code.
            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
                logger.warn("This is warn : " + i);
                logger.error("This is error : " + i);
                logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the log4j.properties file placed under src/main/resources/log4j.properties

> log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
> log4j.appender.file.File=C:\logs\mylog.log
> log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
> log4j.appender.file.threshold=INFO
> log4j.appender.file.Append=true
> log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
> log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=20
> log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{2}:%L - %m%n
> log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
> log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:\logs\mylog%d.log[image] VM configuration:
> -Dlog4j2.debug=true-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=C:\Users****\resources\log4j.properties
>
> pom.xml => log4j-api & log4j-core as dependencies.

Comment: You are using a Log4j 1.x configuration format instead of the Log4j 2.x format recognized by Log4j Core.

Comment: Instead of commenting what is in the pom share the actual definitions (the XML snippet) so we can identify the exact dependency and version used. And don't use images for textual information like logs. Use [code fences format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146138/11748454) on how to convert between the v1 and v2 configuration format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one and set your log path in it and it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] %c{1} %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="info" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="ActiveFileName" value="{YOUR_LOG_FOLDER_PATH}/log4j-current.log" />
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="{YOUR_LOG_FOLDER_PATH}/log4j-%d{HH-mm}.%i.log.gz" />
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000" />
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!--CHANGE name TO ROOT PACKAGE NAME OF YOUR PROJECT THAT YOU WANT TO LOG.-->
    <logger name="org.example" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="info"/>
    </logger>


<!--    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false">-->
<!--        <level value="info"/>-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="info"/>-->
<!--    </logger>-->

<!--    <logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false">-->
<!--        <level value="info"/>-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>-->
<!--        <appender-ref ref="info"/>-->
<!--    </logger>-->

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="info"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```